# Run JQuery before page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, pageload, squarespace

I'm using a fairly rigid template from Squarespace. I need to show a sidebar nav on one page only, Squarespace however does not support this, and shows the side nav in a number of other pages where I don't need it to be.

I've written the following, which works, however it renders the `#rightSidebar` before removing it and altering the page, it takes less than a second, however it still looks pretty poor.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // turn sidebar off on any pages it shouldn't be
    if ($("body").is('.item-main-image, .collection-5a9ebc04e2c4835e358488e3')) {

        // CSS alterations
        $(".collection-type-blog #content").css("width", "100%");
        $(".collection-type-blog #content").css("max-width", "700px");
        $(".collection-type-blog #content").css("display", "block");
        $(".collection-type-blog #content").css("margin", "0 auto");
        $("#rightSidebar").css("display", "none");
        $("#rightSidebar").css("width", "0");
    }

});
```

Is there a way I can stop the `#rightSidebar` from rendering at all, or can I run this body of code before the page loads?

Comment: If I were you I'd avoid setting css with javascript like this, toggle classes instead.

Answer (score 4):

Create a CSS rule to hide the sidebar

```
#rightSidebar { display: none; }
```

In the event that you want it to show, have your javascript make it visible.

```
$('#rightSidebar').show();
```

Making the sidebar display none will keep the browser from trying to render it, preventing the split second between the display and the javascript removing it.